# How to use the same scale with new data? - scikit learn - scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessing, feature-scaling

How do I use the same scale used in preprocessing with new data.

Actual code:

```
x = df.values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

If I understand it correctly I should have included a scaler variable with the StandardScaler.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780302/predicting-new-data-using-sklearn-after-standardizing-the-training-data

Something like:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

What scaler parameters should I use for future data processing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

IMO, you don't need to use scaling if your classifiers are based on decision trees. Also, in your final piece of code, the variable `scaler` is never used, so I am not sure at all why it is defined. Nevertheless, if you insist on using a scaler, you should `Pipeline` it so it automatically applies to the test data the same scaling it has learned by fitting to training data:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('classifier', DecisionTreeClassifier())])
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

Note that you'd obviously need to `import` the necessary modules (I was too lazy to write them here!).

Comment: I edited the question adding the scaling code I used. I am actually running several algos to compare performance. Some need data scaling.

Comment: In your edits, `df_scaled` is not used elsewjere, and you are still training on `X_train` and `y_train` which are derived from `df` (prior to scaling). Anyhow, you can use the `Pipeline` boilerplate code in my answer with all your classifiers; just replace `DecisionTreeClassifier()` with your classifier of choice.

Comment: Thanks!, if I used the min_max_scaler as per my edition, should I just replace StandardScaler in the Pipeline code?

Comment: Yes, just use `MinMaxScaler()` instead of `StandardScaler()`.